# Do we need to start ActiveMQ when configuring through spring?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I get connection refused errors when i try to test activemq using spring jms integration. Do i need to start the activemq server or something? From my understanding spring would have all the methods to start the active mq when i setup the brokerconnction

### source

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myJmsContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(new ActiveMQQueue("jms.queue"));
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://:61616");
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Clean out any ActiveMQ data from previous run
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));

        // Launch the application
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        // Send a message
        MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {

            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage("ping!");
            }
        };

        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        System.out.println("Sending a new message");
        jmsTemplate.send("mailbox-destination", messageCreator);
    }
}
```

### Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:580)
    at org.blanc.whiteboard.jms.Application.main(Application.java:67)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `vm://localhost` URL, an in-memory broker will be started on the vm transport; if you use the `tcp://...` url you need to start an external broker, or add a broker bean to your application.